# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context.t0.response.data')]

Tags: react-native

How can I resolve this error?
The error is showing that there is something that is not an object but I can't find it.

code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const load_barber_shops = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await api.post( '/api/barbearia/best' );

            setBarbers( response.data.details );

        } catch ( error ) {
            const { details } = error.response.data;

            if ( details ) {
                Alert.alert( 'Aviso: 1', details );
            } else {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Aviso:',
                    'Não foi possível carregar as barbearias. Por favor, tente novamente em breve.'
                );
            }
            navigation.navigate("AuthRoutes", {screen: "LoginCliente"});
        }
    };

    load_barber_shops();
}, [] );
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you aint getting data back from the api. Are you sure you want to post something to the api? or are you trying to get something. In that case it should be

```js
const response = await api.get( '/api/barbearia/best' );
```